# FluentAssertions Compare two IQueryables

Tags: iqueryable, fluent-assertions

I have two Iqueryables which have different values. I want to use FluentAssertions to compare the elements in the Iqueryable for my Unittests.

What I have is the following:

```
[Fact]
public void TestCompareIQueryables()
{
    // Arrange
    var objects1 = new CustomObject[]
    {
        new CustomObject {
            Code = "Code1",
            Name = "Name1"
        }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var objects2 = new CustomObject []
    {
        new CustomObject {
            Code = "Code2",
            Name = "Name2"
    }
    }.AsQueryable();

    // Assert
    objects1.Should().HaveSameCount(objects2);
    objects1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(objects1);
    objects1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(objects2);
}
```

What is happening when I run this fact, is that it passes, but I expect the last Should().BeEquivalentTo() to fail.

Am I missing something that make the test not act as expected here? How can I compare each element to eachother in two IQueryables correctly?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does `CustomObject` implement `Equals`?

Comment: What version of `FluentAssertions` are you using?
How is `CustomObject` implemented?

When I copy your provided code and make a `CustomObject` class with only the two properties, it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, in the meantime I have found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is in another call from FluentAssertions:

```
objects1.Should().BeSameAs(objects2);
```

This gives the expected error.